# Por que imagen no se pone en Contain? HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Espero que anden bien.

Tengo un inconveniente con la seccion `Hero`, donde tengo un `slider` que quiero acomodar que la imagen se vea toda, y bien en el centro.

Tengo las siguientes etiquetas:

```
<section class="hero container">
            <div class="slider">
                <figure class="hero-imagen-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img class="hero-imagen" src="./images/fibra1.jpg"></li>
                        <li><img class="hero-imagen" src="./images/fibra2.jpg"></li>
                    </ul>
                 </figure>
            </div>
    </section>
```

con la hoja de style:

```
.slider{
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: inherit;
}  
.slider ul{
    display:flex;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400%;
    animation: cambio 20s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
} 
.slider li{
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.slider img{
    width:100%;
}
@keyframes cambio{
    0% { margin-left: 0;}
    20% { margin-left: 0;}

    25% { margin-left: -100%;}
    45% { margin-left: -100%;}

    50% { margin-left: -200%;}
    70% { margin-left: -200%;}

    75% { margin-left: -300%;}
    100% { margin-left: -300%;}
}
.hero{
    height:300px;
    background-color:#1c2227;
    position:relative;
    z-index:500;
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-flow:column;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center
}
.hero-imagen-container{
    margin:0;
    position:relative
}
.hero-imagen{
    object-fit:contain
}
```

Tengo el problema que las imágenes no se ven muy bien, este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, la imagen esta cortada. agregue `containt:content` pero no alcanzo. no encontré donde puede estar el error.

Agradezco por su tiempo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo ? de alguna forma te sirvió la respuesta ?

Answer (score 0):

me toco utilizar imágenes de `Internet` , solo cambia `width: 100%;` por `width: auto;` de la clase **`.slider img{`** y eso pone la imagen como se debe de ver, también cambia el `padding: 0;` por `padding: 10;` de la clase **`.slider ul{`** y eso centra la imagen revisa este snipet

```css
.slider{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: inherit;
}  
.slider{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: inherit;
}  
.slider ul{
    display:flex;
    padding: 10;
    width: 400%;
    animation: cambio 20s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
} 
.slider li{
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.slider img{
    width: auto;
}
@keyframes cambio{
    0% { margin-left: 0;}
    20% { margin-left: 0;}

    25% { margin-left: -100%;}
    45% { margin-left: -100%;}

    50% { margin-left: -200%;}
    70% { margin-left: -200%;}

    75% { margin-left: -300%;}
    100% { margin-left: -300%;}
}
.hero{
    height:auto;
    background-color:#1c2227;
    position:relative;
    z-index:500;
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-flow:column;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center
}
.hero-imagen-container{
    margin:0;
    position:relative
}
.hero-imagen{
    object-fit:contain
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero container">
            <div class="slider">
                <figure class="hero-imagen-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img class="hero-imagen" src="https://venngage-wordpress.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2018/05/youtube-banner-template-1.png"></li>
                        <li><img class="hero-imagen" src="https://venngage-wordpress.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2018/05/youtube-banner-template-1.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                 </figure>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Ejecuta el snippet y le das `Pagina completa`